# Регулярное выражение - является ли текст ссылкой

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, re

Принимается на вход текст, мне нужно определить является ли этот текст ссылкой. Совсем не силен в регулярках, так что взял такое, оно, в отличии от остальных, более чем хорошо справляется со своей задачей, кроме того, что обязательно нужна ссылка с протоколом. Можно ли сделать первое условие, проверку на http/https необязательной?

```
url_regex = re.compile(
    r'^(?:http|ftp)s?://'  # http:// or https://
    r'(?:(?:[A-Z0-9](?:[A-Z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2,6}\.?|[A-Z0-9-]{2,}\.?)|'  # domain...
    r'localhost|'  # localhost...
    r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})'  # ...or ip
    r'(?::\d+)?'  # optional port
    r'(?:/?|[/?]\S+)$', re.IGNORECASE)
```

Comment: Замените `r'^(?:http|ftp)s?://'` на `r'^(?:(?:http|ftp)s?://)?'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замените `r'^(?:http|ftp)s?://'` на `r'^(?:(?:http|ftp)s?://)?'`.

С помощью `(?:...)?` можно любую часть регулярного выражения сделать необязательной. `(?:...)` — незахватывающая подмаска, а `?` — квантификатор, делающий шаблон слева опциональным (находит его "один или ноль раз").

```py
url_regex = re.compile(
    r'^(?:(?:http|ftp)s?://)?'  # Необязательные http:// или https://
    r'(?:(?:[A-Z0-9](?:[A-Z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2,6}\.?|[A-Z0-9-]{2,}\.?)|'  # domain...
    r'localhost|'  # localhost...
    r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})'  # ...or ip
    r'(?::\d+)?'  # optional port
    r'(?:/?|[/?]\S+)$', re.IGNORECASE)
```